# When starting Tomcat it looks like two different JAVA_HOME paths are being concatenated together

Tags: tomcat, java

When I try to start tomcat it doesn't work.

When I look in tomcat/logs/catalina.out I get the line:

- ./catalina.sh: 454: /usr/bin/java/bin/java: not found

This makes sense since there is no `/usr/bin/java/bin/java` but there is a `/usr/bin/java`

It looks like Catalina is adding an extra portion onto the JAVA_HOME variable. When I do `echo $JAVA_HOME` I get `/usr/bin/java`

Does anyone know how I can solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `/etc/tomcat.conf` (could be tomcat(versionnumber).conf and make sure you're not over-riding the system value there.